# Stop page from appearing in browser history

Tags: html, redirect, browser-history

I have a simple flow:

```
A.html -> B.html -> C.html
```

Now, page **B** either 302's (temporarily redirects giving 302 redirect code) to page **C**, or it shows a progress bar; then, after an ajax call is done, it redirects to page **C**. When the user is on **C**, and they hit "Back" I want them to end up on **A** instead of **B**.

If the page did the 302 redirect, then the back behavior is what I want. Otherwise they get that intermediary page. Is there any way to solve this easily?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Presumably when the Ajax is done you are using:

```
location.href = "http://example.com/c";
```

Change that to:

```
location.replace("http://example.com/c");
```

Comment: no guarantee solution. Think phones, playstation browser, etc.

Comment: @Xaade — do you have any evidence to suggest that those browsers support the location object but not its replace method?

Answer (score 2):

Use ajax in A to load B into A.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. That's a function of the browser itself, and not something generally exposed to the page's desires. You'd be better off having page A do an AJAX call instead of loading page B in the main window at all.