# Does Android support window.location.replace or any equivalent?

Tags: android, mobile, browser, browser-history, window.location

It seems that the Android browser doesn't properly implement `window.location.replace`.

In most browsers, calling `window.location.replace` will replace the current URL with the URL passed to it.

When the user navigates somewhere else then clicks back, they'll be returned to the URL that was passed to `window.location.replace`, rather than the URL that they were at before `window.location.replace` was called.

The Android browser doesn't seem to implement this properly.

In the Android browser, the user will be directed back to the *original URL* rather than the one passed to `window.location.replace`.

You can test this for yourself [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jorgenfb/mtTwj/1/show/light/).

So is there any alternative way to re-write history in Android? Or will I just have to live without that feature, for Android users?

Comment: try document.location

Comment: @jonathanconway did u get the answer. In my case location.replace does not remove the previous URL. If u got the answer then please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and ended up with code similar to chris suggestion, but I changed the if statement to use modernizr's feature detection. 
If you're not using modernizr the code would look something like this:

```
if(!!(window.history && history.replaceState)){
   window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, base + fragment);
} else {
   location.replace(base + fragment);
}
```

Unless you have a specific reason for device detection, feature detection is preferred since it basically supports all devices, even future ones.

Comment: I don't understand "base" and "fragment". Can you explain more clearly?

Comment: I used base + fragment from Chris' example below. But it it simply just a string with the url (relative or absolute) that you want to add to the history.

Answer (score 1):

To make it work across all/most mobile platforms check out this [link](http://www.chrislinford.co.uk/get-going-guides/add-ons/iphoneandandroid.html).

Shows how to handle redirect for Android, iPad and iPhone.

Android uses `document.location` whereas iOS supports `window.location.replace`

Comment: So in other words, Android doesn't support any means of changing the URL without the previous URL remaining in history?

Comment: I'm not sure, try something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864633/assigning-to-document-location-href-without-clobbering-history) and see if that helps

Comment: The link you sent doesn't solve the problem. Yes, it redirects the user and keeps the redirect URL in history. But the original URL remains in history too. Whereas I wanted to completely wipe the original URL out of history. It looks like this isn't possible then, on Android. :(

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
document.location.href = 'http://example.com/somePage.html';
```

Comment: This will work if I just want to change the URL, but it won't work if I want to keep the previous URL out of the browser history. The above solution will keep the previous URL in history.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the replaceState method on the history window.history

```
      if (((navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('mozilla/5.0') > -1 && navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('android ') > -1 && navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('applewebkit') > -1) && !(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1))) {
          window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, base + fragment);
      } else {
          location.replace(base + fragment);
      }
```