# Meta refresh and redirect a page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, meta-tags

I creates a webpage with a META tag exactly like this :

```
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=http://www.google.com">
```

The problem is that mobile browsers does not support this meta tag, although it does redirect properly in web on every browser.

full code of webpage is here :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <META http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=http://www.google.com">
<script>

var URL = "mziiki://app";
var MARKET = "market://details?id=com.spice.mziiki";
var APPLEMARKET = "https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/mziiki/id875256574?ls=1&mt=8";
var PLAYSTORE = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spice.mziiki";
var ITUNES = "mziiki://app";

function onLoad() {

    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/)) {

        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrome/)) {

             window.location = "intent://app#Intent;package=com.spice.mziiki;scheme=mziiki;end;";

        } else {

            // Older Android browser
            var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
            iframe.style.border = "none";
            iframe.style.width = "1px";
            iframe.style.height = "1px";
            var t = setTimeout(function() {
                window.location = MARKET;
            }, 1000);
            iframe.onload = function () { clearTimeout(call) };
            iframe.src = URL;
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);

        }

     } else if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/)) {
         // IOS
         setTimeout(function() {
             if (!document.webkitHidden)
                 window.location = APPLEMARKET;
         }, 25);

         window.location = ITUNES;

     } else {

         // Not mobile
         window.location = PLAYSTORE;
     }
}
</script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad()">
  </body>
</html>
```

What's going on here? I can't find a solution, so does mobile browsers make up it's own rules ?

Anyone have a similar problem ?

Comment: I think your problem is similar to this one: [Does Android support window.location.replace or any equivalent?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193359/does-android-support-window-location-replace-or-any-equivalent

Comment: @agna meta tag not working. according to meta tag. Page will be redirected to the www.google.com after 5 seconds. But its not working.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use PHP for redirect to a webpage... The user can't change the HEADER, the code in PHP is:

```
<?php header("Location: dir/file.php") ; ?>
```

Insert it in your code on top of the page...

Oh, i don't see the time to wait, in PHP you can do like this:

```
<?php  header( "refresh:5;url=page.php" ); ?>
```

Where in Refresh you write the seconds to wait