# How to make redirect to instagram://user?username={username}

Tags: javascript, android, html, redirect, http-redirect

i have this link on my html page that open Instagram app on specific user:

```
<a href="instagram://user?username={USERNAME}">Link to Instagram Profile</a>
```

I was looking for the ways to run the url 'instagram://user?username={USERNAME}' automatically (like automatic redirect).

Here is what i've tried in the head:

1.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=instagram://user?username={USERNAME}" />
```

2.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.href = "instagram://user?username={USERNAME}"
</script>
```

3. variation suggested by @Nitin-bagoriya

```
<script> function load() { window.location.href = "instagram://user?username={USERNAME}"}; window.onload = load; </script>
```

4. variation suggested by @Giuseppe

   addEventListener('load', load);

But when i browse there - nothing happen.
It was tested on android with instagram app installed.

I wonder is there any way to run Instagram app automatically via redirect so user dont need to click the link?

Comment: Later you will ux-check whether instagram is defined or not, won't you? In dev time, you could alert something in the case instagram is not defined, so you know it flows as you expect.

Comment: @Giuseppe, sorry not sure what defined mean, but only users with instagram app installed can land on this page.

Comment: Then it's unnecessary. Perfect :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recaping, so others can benefit.

### 0. Main problem:

Javascript solutions based in "window.location.href" are not supported in mobile OS (iOS or Android).

### 1. Solution in PHP:

What seemed to first work is adding the redirect in PHP, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25918531/1414176), like this:

```
<?php header("Location: instagram://user?username={USERNAME}") ; ?>
```

### 2. (Better) solution in Javascript:

iOS provides "window.location.**replace**" to do a redirect, while what Android provides is "**document**.location". Thus, you need to device-detect first, and then apply the proper redirect.

```
var destination = "instagram://user?username={USERNAME}"; 
if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) ) {
  // use Android's redirect
  document.location = destination;   
}   
else {
  // use iOS redirect
  window.location.replace( destination );
}
```

See here for details: [iOS and Android redirects in javascript](http://www.chrislinford.co.uk/get-going-guides/add-ons/iphoneandandroid.html)

Answer (score 2):

You Just need to add **window.onLoad** in head section of .html file

Your Final code will be like:

> **window.onLoad = window.location.href = "instagram://user?username={USERNAME}"**

OR you can create a function which contain your **window.location.href = "instagram://user?username={USERNAME}"** and execute it on **window.onload**  !

Comment: Hi @Nitin-bagoriya, thanks for your help.
The window is not reloading though. I've used your code as well as this one that i put stright after the 
`<head>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
      function load() {
        window.location.href = "instagram://user?username={username};
      }
      window.onload = load;
    </script>`

Comment: Copy and paste below code . it will work :)
<script>
 function load() { window.location.href = "instagram://user?username=elemtseva"};
 window.onload = load; 
</script>

1. You have added semicolon after elemtseva and missing " after it

Comment: Thanks,
Hmm still doesnt work, when i do window.onload = load - there is no redirection. When i use window.onload = load() - just white screen..

Comment: i've just used you code and no redirect happen. When i add 'http://' - there is redirect...

Comment: If Works then  Congrats :)
there is error in your url which doesn't contain valid url btw

Comment: no it doesn't, i added 'http://' just to confirm there is no JS error in the code. The problem is that it doesn't work for 'instagram://....'. In the sae time when user click link with href='instagram://...' - it works (instagram will run in this case).

Comment: Try "addEventListener('load', load);" instead of window.onload(). Maybe Android doesn't 'like' window.onload.

Comment: @Nitin-bagoriya nope it doesnt work. Can you have a look at the original question please?..

Comment: @Giuseppe just tried it, didn't work. Thanks for suggestion though.

Comment: Just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25918472/meta-refresh-and-redirect-a-page They suggest you need to add the redirect in PHP.

Comment: @NitinBagoriya Could you please update your answer to show what needed to be done? This way the OP can accept it :)

Comment: Hello @Giuseppe :)
Well @user912830823 you just copy and paste the following code and it works 

`<script>
 function load() { window.location.href = "https://instagram.com/user/?username=elemtseva"};
 window.onload = setTimeout(load, 1); 
</script>` 

First thing we forget is Instagram use https instead of http thus it redirect our url to https protocol and @user912830823 says it show blank page to remove this we using setTimeout javascript function .
And now its working  Perfect with No issues :)