# Redirect to another page on document.ready in android browsers

Tags: javascript, android, html, redirect, user-interface

Im trying to redirect to another html page on load of one page. Below is my code (I want to automatically load 2.html when i open 1.html)
**P.S:** I could not use window.location.href because of specific use case

**1.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript">

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        //$("#second")[0].click();
        document.getElementById("second").click(); 
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href = "2.html" id="second"/> click </a>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried **$("#second")[0].click()** and **document.getElementById("second").click()**. Both works fine in desktop browsers. But in android Both doesn't seems to work. 
Do we have any ways to achieve it ? Please Help

Comment: To redirect a page in mobile check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193359/does-android-support-window-location-replace-or-any-equivalent

Comment: Hi mot, I could not use window.location.href/replace since I need this 1.html to be in browser history.

Comment: Check out the solution in the question I sent, replacing `replaceState` with `pushState` should do the trick for you. It seems to be working in android but it used not to work and some version will work with it and some won't. Maybe you can use a fallback without history modification in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code.

## Solution 1

```
<script>
    function newPage() {
        window.location.assign("http://www.adarshkr.com")
    }
 </script>
```

## Solution 2

```
<script>    
    var url = "http://stackoverflow.com";    
    $(location).attr('href',url);

</script>
```

Comment: This Script does the redirection in android. But the problem is It doesnt add the history entry for my 1.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mod and @samsad. I resolved it in the following way,

```
 <html>
        <head>
            <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
            <script type = "text/javascript">

            window.onunload = function(){};
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                history.pushState({}, "", "1.html");
                var url = "2.html";    
                window.location.assign(url);
            });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <a href = "2.html" id="second"/> click </a>
        </body>
        </html>
```