# Mobiles not detecting anchor change to toggle menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

Hi I have made a website using fullpage.js which is great and scrolls between sections (full pages) but on mobiles it can be difficult to navigate so I have made it continuos scrolling when the width is under 640px.

I have a menu which toggles down after the anchor changes from the main page and toggles back when the anchor is the main page. this is because there is a built in menu on the main page so it doesn't need a 2nd.

On mobiles after making it continuos scrolling this feature doesn't work but it still works on computer browsers. I don't know whether I am over looking something or if I could write a better script for the menu toggle.
Please look at www.themeltingpotkitchen.com to see what I mean.

Here is my menu js. I will point out that if your tap links via menus it will work but not by scrolling :s

```
// detect anchor change and hide or show menu
        function locationHashChanged() {
            var hash = location.hash;
            var id = hash.replace(/^#/, '');
            // logic
            if (id == 'Home') {
                $("#nav_hide").slideUp();
            } else if (id == 'About') {
                $("#nav_hide").slideDown();
            } else if (id == 'Trailer') {
                $("#nav_hide").slideDown();
            } else if (id == 'Food') {
                $("#nav_hide").slideDown();
            } else if (id == 'Contact') {
                $("#nav_hide").slideDown();
            }
        }
        window.onhashchange = locationHashChanged;

        // if loaded page is home hide menu
        var hashVal = window.location.hash.split("#")[1];

        var p = window.location.pathname.split("/");
        var filename = p[p.length-1];

        if(hashVal == 'Home', filename == 'index.html') {
            $("#nav_hide").hide();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be using the change in the URL to trigger any action. That's not the way to do it with fullPage.js.
You should be using the callbacks provided by the plugin such as `onLeave` or `afterLoad`. 
Or you could even use the class added to the body element as suggested in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiCVPpI9l3M)

The reason for it is because fullPage.js doesn't change the location hash but [uses the HTML5 History API](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/jquery.fullPage.js#L1752) for mobile phones due to [problems with the location hash behaviour in Mobile Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193359/does-android-support-window-location-replace-or-any-equivalent):

```
//Mobile Chrome doesn't work the normal way, so... lets use HTML5 for phones :)
if (isTouchDevice || isTouch) {
    history.replaceState(undefined, undefined, '#' + url);
} else {
    var baseUrl = window.location.href.split('#')[0];
    window.location.replace(baseUrl + '#' + url);
}
```

Comment: Thank You Alvaro! please could you link your video to this? as changing the menu with css transitions using the change on the body tag was VERY helpful and I think anyone else with a similar problem would appreciate this! I will be using this again to animate future websites!