# Vue router doesn't work on some Androids. Is there a workaround?

Tags: android, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vue-router

I am building an app that is using Google authentication through firebase and that needs to redirect the user from a **login.vue** component to an **/hello** path upon successful authentication.

I have first tried doing it the normal vue way:

```
  this.$router.replace('/hello')
```

only to realise my Samsung Galaxy J5 wasn't having it...

All is working on other devices and browsers (so far) using the normal Vue routing tools but on some Android devices Vue is refusing to collaborate. I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193359/does-android-support-window-location-replace-or-any-equivalent) some Android versions do not like the way the Vue dynamic routing transpiles to vanilla JS so I am attempting the following (still, no success).

This is my code on the **created** hook of component **login.vue** when Google auth (with redirection, not pop up) returns to it:

```
    created() {    
        firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(result => {
            var user = result.user;
                if (user) {                               
                var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
                var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; 
                if(isAndroid) { // NOT WORKING (stays on Login.vue although I am sure it's detecting it's an Android)
                    window.location.href = window.location.host + '/hello';   
                } else {
                    this.$router.replace('/hello') // this work perfectly
                     console.log(window.location.host + "/hello" ); // this is returning the intended address: localhost:8080/hello        
                }
            } else {                     
                toastr.warning("Oops something went wrong on login!");         
            }
            }).catch(error => {
                // dealing with redirection result errors from Google Authentication
        });
```

This is my index.js routing file (I am doing some route guarding here so it may be useful for you to get a bigger picture if I paste the file):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import firebase from '../firebase-config'
import {store} from '@/store/store'
import hello from '@/components/hello'
import login from '@/components/login'
import landing from '@/components/landing'


Vue.use(Router)
let router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '*',
      redirect: '/landing'
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      redirect: '/landing'
    },
    {
      path: '/landing',
      name: 'landing',
      component: landing
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      component: login
    },
    {
      path: '/hello',
      name: 'hello',
      component: hello,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    },
  ],
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => { 
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (!user) {
          next({
              path: '/landing'
          })
      } else {
          next()
      }
    });
  } else {
    next()
  }
})

export default router
```

Any thoughts?