# window.location.replace() on mobile changes to default (different) browser

Tags: javascript, browser, window.location

User starts on mobile Chrome browser and in the process we call `window.location.replace(url)` to redirect user to another URL. However, user's mobile device default browser is Safari, so the new URL page is opened on Safari browser. Can I somehow control that the new page after calling `window.location.replace(url)` is opened on the same browser (Chrome)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @AlexandreElshobokshy More information is not really necessary in this case I would think. I normally is the first to post what your posted

Comment: Perhaps this is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193359/does-android-support-window-location-replace-or-any-equivalent

Comment: I also see `window.history.pushState("", "", "new url");
window.location.reload();` posted a few places